# Multiple Result Data in json Response

Tags: php

I am new in PHP and trying to build one API which provide me json response of required data. There one table called user and I need email, username and user_type from it. I have coded like below for do it

```
$result = array();
$users = getOnlineUsers($conn);
    $userinfo['email'] = $users['email'];
    $userinfo['username'] = $users['username'];
    $userinfo['user_type'] = $users['user_type'];
    $result['status'] ="success";
    $result['userData'] = $userinfo;
```

And function is like below

```
function getOnlineUsers($conn)
    {
        $q  = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_users WHERE online_status = 1");
       // $q->bind_param("s", $email);
        $q->execute();


        $result = $q->store_result();
        $metaResults = $q->result_metadata();
        $fields = $metaResults->fetch_fields();
        $statementParams='';
         foreach($fields as $field){
             if(empty($statementParams)){
                 $statementParams.="\$column['".$field->name."']";
             }else{
                 $statementParams.=", \$column['".$field->name."']";
             }
        }
        $statment="\$q->bind_result($statementParams);";
        eval($statment);
        $q->fetch();

        return $column;
    }
```

Its working fine but giving me only one row in response. I want get all row instead of one. I am getting response like this

```
{"status":"success","userData":{"email":"abc@gmail.com","username":"rajrathodbvn","user_type":0}}
```

Let me know if someone can help me for solve my issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a lot of code for something so simple.  Select the columns you want:

```
function getOnlineUsers($conn) {
    $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT email, username, user_type
                                FROM table_users
                                WHERE online_status = 1");
    $q->execute();
    return $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Then assign:

```
$result['status'] = 'success';
$result['userData'] = getOnlineUsers($conn);
```

Or:

```
$result = ['status' => 'success', 'userData' => getOnlineUsers($conn)];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! its what I was looking for.